# The value of req.body is undefined REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, axios

I am creating REST API application. I have front-end (Nuxt.js) and API (Express.js), and I am trying to send data from front-end to API. Api works on port 3001 and front on port 8010.

So, the sending of data looks like this:

Function on front:

```js
  methods: {
    async postTip() {
      const test = await postTipFunc({
        content: this.tipContent
      })
    }
  }
```

Here is `postTipFunc` function `(project_front/api/index.js)`:

```
import axios from "axios";
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'


const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8010/',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})

export const postTipFunc = async payload => {
  const { data } =  await api.post(`p-t`, payload)
  return data
}
```

Here is end-point which goes to back-end `(project_front/server/routes/index.js)`:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0'
const { Router } = require('express')
const axios = require('axios')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config()

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3001/",
})

const router = Router()

router.post(`/p-t`, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await api.post(`/post-tip`, req.body)
    res.json(data.data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
})

module.exports = router
```

And finally back-end `(prodect_api/src/routes/index.js)`:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const wrapAsync = require('./../middlewares/async')
const tipController = require('../controllers/tip')

router.post(
  "/post-tip",
  wrapAsync(tipController.postTip)
)

module.exports = router;
```

Actually, that function `tipController.postTip` just receive data and shows it in console, so, it makes no sense to show it.

Also, if it can help, `console.log()` shows data only here - `project_front/api/index.js`. After that point everything is `undefined`

So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, here is answer, to make things work you need to install `body-parse` into your API. Just like that:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Hope, it'll help someone!